# Dagger2 difference between modules and dependincies

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am failing to understand the difference between telling a component what are his modules and telling the component what are its component dependencies.

For example:

```
@Module public class ModuleA {
    @Provides DependencyA providesDependencyA() {
        return new DependencyA();
    }
}

@Module public class ModuleB {
    @Provides DependencyB providesDependencyB() {
        return new DependencyB();
    }
}

@Component (modules = {ModuleA.class}) 
public interface ComponentA {
    DependencyA getDependencyA();
}
```

what is the difference between this:

```
@Component (modules = {ModuleA.class, ModuleB.class}) 
public interface ComponentB {
    DependencyB getDependencyB();
}
```

And that:

```
@Component (dependencies = {ComponentA.class}, modules = {ModuleB.class})
public interface ComponentB {
    DependencyB getDependencyB();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your simple case, they behave roughly the same; if you'd like, you can think of Dagger's treatment of component dependencies as though it installs an automatically-generated Module that wraps each *provision method* (zero-arg factory method) on the dependency with a `@Provides` method that delegates to the instance you pass in. In either case, Dagger will generate a Factory/Provider class implementation that delegates to the module/dependency method you consume.

However, there are some big differences, including these:

- Modules can take other arbitrary per-method parameters sourced from your object graph. Provision methods in component dependencies have to be zero-arg. This is the most significant difference: Component dependencies are pure external factories, not full participants in your object graph.
- Module provision methods have to be declared with `@Provides` for Dagger to consume them, which also allows for non-exposed zero-arg methods. Component dependencies treat every single zero-arg method as a potential provider.
- Modules have to be annotated with `@Module`. Component dependencies can be arbitrary types (*not necessarily just `@Component`-annotated instances*), and you can pass any implementation whether or not Dagger generates it.
- Modules and module methods will have their scopes checked; they must be compatible with the enclosing Component's scope. Component dependencies aren't scope-checked.
- Modules can be abstract classes or interfaces, letting you use `@Binds` to express declarative bindings within your graph. Component dependencies are instances by definition, and have no access to anything in your object graph.
- Of course, Modules can declare subcomponents they use or their dependencies on other modules. Component dependencies can do neither; they're just external factories.
- Instantiable modules don't need to be supplied in a component builder if they have zero-arg public methods. Component dependencies [must be provided](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.Builder.html), even if you were to provide a concrete type Dagger could instantiate.

In short, treat modules as *configuration of your graph* and component dependencies as *externs from outside your graph*. Other than the narrow overlap you've described above, it should be pretty clear which role you want for any given class.