# Understanding dependency injection in Java with Dagger

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am familiar with the dependency inversion principle in traditional design patterns, where you have an abstract product that performs tasks in a class that requests a factory method. But dependency injection is different in that it uses annotations to generate products.

I am reviewing this [Dagger 2](https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide) example. This is the end result:

```
// CoffeeApp.java
public class CoffeeApp {
  @Singleton
  @Component(modules = { DripCoffeeModule.class })
  public interface Coffee {
    CoffeeMaker maker();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Coffee coffee = DaggerCoffeeApp_Coffee.builder().build();
    coffee.maker().brew();
  }
}

$ java -cp ... coffee.CoffeeApp
~ ~ ~ heating ~ ~ ~
=> => pumping => =>
 [_]P coffee! [_]P
```

I'm having trouble understanding this line right here:

```
 CoffeeMaker maker();
```

In the CoffeeMaker class, there is no make() method. So how does this work?

This is my understanding:

The CoffeeMaker class uses the @Inject annotation in its constructor:

```
@Inject CoffeeMaker(Lazy<Heater> heater, Pump pump) {
  this.heater = heater;
  this.pump = pump;
}
```

This will force Dagger to instantiate a new Heater and a new Pump whenever a CoffeeMaker is instantiated, is that correct? Or does the CoffeeMaker class itself just needs to be referenced? The document says this:

> When you request a CoffeeMaker, it’ll obtain one by calling new
>   CoffeeMaker() and setting its injectable fields.

BUt what does it mean by request?

When it says, it will set its injectable fields, I notice that Heater and Pump are interfaces. There is a corresponding PumpModule class with the @Module annotation. And it contains the method `providePump`.

The document says:

```
The method’s return type defines which dependency it satisfies.
```

Does this mean that when  `@Inject CoffeeMaker` constructor is called, it in turn discovers the pump reference and searches for the PumpModule @Module and then discovers providePump and instantiates a new pump of type Thermosiphon?

Comment: Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41472319/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-getter-methods-in-components-in-dagger-2) for an explanation of the `maker()` method inside the Component

Answer (score 1):

Dagger is a *compile-time* dependency injection solution.

The line `CoffeeMaker maker()` on the interface `CoffeeApp.Coffee`, annotated as it is, means that Dagger will *generate and compile an implementation of `CoffeeApp.Coffee`* that has an implementation for the `maker` method which will provide you a fully-injected CoffeeMaker instance. If you'd like, you can look at the file that Dagger generates, DaggerCoffeeApp_Coffee.java, which looks a lot like the implementation on [slide 41 of the original Dagger 2 talk](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1fby5VeGU9CN8zjw4lAb2QPPsKRxx6mSwCe9q7ECNSJQ/pub?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000&slide=id.g36c3b6490_02). (Slides 35 and 36 show the corresponding Factory/Provider implementaitons Dagger writes.)

> This will force Dagger to instantiate a new Heater and a new Pump whenever a CoffeeMaker is instantiated, is that correct?

Yes, usually. Though it is your prerogative to return an *existing* instance in a `@Provides` method, or use an annotation like `@Singleton` to let Dagger manage an existing instance, Dagger's default behavior is to create a new instance for each dependency, and create a new instance for each of the dependencies of that dependency, and so forth.

> Does this mean that when  @Inject CoffeeMaker constructor is called, it in turn discovers the pump reference and searches for the PumpModule @Module and then discovers providePump and instantiates a new pump of type Thermosiphon?

You are *nearly* correct: To produce that implementation, Dagger will inspect the `@Inject CoffeeMaker` constructor, discover that the CoffeeMaker needs a Heater and a Pump, and so forth. For frameworks like Guice, that does all happen at runtime, but for Dagger all of that analysis and mapping happens at compile time. In your example, the `@Provides Pump` method exists in DripCoffeeModule, which Dagger doesn't search for: The example provides it through the `@Component` annotation on CoffeeApp.Coffee.

Answer (score 0):

@Donato, you're right, `CoffeeMaker` doesn't have a `maker()` method, it's the `Coffee` interface that does have the `maker()` method. And that method (`maker()`) returns an object of type `CoffeMaker`. So in your example, `DaggerCoffeeApp_Coffee.builder().build();` would return an implementation of `Coffee`, which in turn implements the `maker()` method.

**Question:** "*BUt what does it mean by request?*"

**My Answer:** Request means injection (i.e. wherever you see `@Inject`). So, for example, the following private variable declaration "requests" an instance of `CoffeeMaker`,

```
public MyClass {
  @Inject private CoffeeMaker maker;
  ...
}
```

And `CoffeeMaker`, in turn, "requests" an instance or `Heater` and an instance of `Pump`:

```
@Inject CoffeeMaker(Lazy<Heater> heater, Pump pump) {
  this.heater = heater;
  this.pump = pump;
}
```

So an instance of `Heater` and an instance of `Pump` will be instantiated and injected when instantiating (or injecting) `maker`.

**Question:** "*Does this mean that when  @Inject CoffeeMaker constructor is called, it in turn discovers the pump reference and searches for the PumpModule @Module and then discovers providePump and instantiates a new pump of type Thermosiphon?*"

**My Answer:** That's right.