# Modules with mixed scopes

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I am trying to achieve the following behavior:

- Use an object provided by a module under a singleton scope in another module with a different scope.

Here is what I have. I have tried a lot of changes based on several answers but I still cannot solve this issue.

The first module (Should be bound to the application's lifecycle)

```
@Module
public class AModule {

private Context context;

public AModule(Context context) {
   this.context = context;
}    

@Provides
@Singleton
MySharedPreference provideMySharedPreference(SharedPreferences prefs) {
   return new MySharedPreferences(prefs);
}

@Provides
@Singleton
SharedPreference provideSharedPreference() {
   return context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
}
```

It's component

```
@Component(modules = AModule.class)
@Singleton
public interface AComponent {
   void inject(...);
}
```

The second module (bounded to Activity Lifecycle)

```
@Module
public class BModule {

   @Provides
   @ActivityScope
   X provideX(MySharedPreferences prefs) {
      return new Y(prefs);
   }
}
```

It's component

```
@Component(modules = BModule.class)
@ActivityScope
public interface BComponent {
   Y Y();
}
```

I declared the Activity Scope

```
@Scope
@Retenion(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ActivityScope{}
```

And MySharedPreferences is as follows

```
public class MySharedPreferences {

   private SharedPreferences mSharedPrefs;

   @Inject
   public MySharedPreferences(SharedPreferences prefs) {
      mSharedPrefs = prefs;
   }

   // some methods
}
```

Finally, in my application class, I create the A Component

```
aComponent = DaggerAComponent.builder().aModule(new AModule(getApplicationContext())).build();
```

**EDIT** Some of the things I tried

I tried adding `includes = AModule.class` to the BModule.
I tried adding `dependencies = AComponent.class` to the BComponent.
I tried creating a new Component with the ActivityScope annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using dependent components (`dependencies =`) you need to write a provision method to expose the dependency from the `@Singleton` scoped component to the `@ActivityScope` component.

```
@Component(modules = AModule.class)
@Singleton
public interface AComponent {
   void inject(...);

   SharedPreferences exposeSharedPreferences();
}
```

The provision method will allow the dependent `@ActivityScope` component to use `@Singleton` binding for `SharedPreferences`:

```
@Component(modules = BModule.class, dependencies = AComponent.class)
@ActivityScope
public interface BComponent {
   Y Y();
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41472319/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-getter-methods-in-components-in-dagger-2) for a more detailed explanation of provision methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now I understand. I had actually tried something similar to solve the issue but now it is much clearer.